# Include colored box, rotated text in booktabs styled table

Tags: booktabs

I am trying to make a latex table that looks like the picture. There should basically be 4 columns of rotated text under Header 1, one grey cell that that contains additional information. I am new to latex and have no idea how to make this table in booktabs style. [image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\turn{\rotatebox[origin=b]{90}}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array, caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}


\begin{document}
 
\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Header 1} &     \\ 
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
&\turn{Text1}      &\turn{Text2}     &\turn{Text3}     & \turn{Text4}     & \cellcolor{gray!25} \makecell[l]{Some line 1\\ Some line 1\\ Some line 1\\ Some line 1\\ Some line 1} \\
Header 3 &    &      &        &       &Header 3\\
\midrule

&        &       &       &       &    \\
&        &       &       &       &    \\
\bottomrule

\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! What you want to have is not clear from the image. Does each of the columns under Header 1 correspond to a rotated tex?

Comment: Yes. Each of the columns under header 1 should be rotated and aligned at bottom.

Comment: Could you post a code of what you've tried, so we don't have to type everything from scratch?

Comment: Please check the updated question.

Comment: I've compiled your code. What would you like to change, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image]

MWE, which reproduce this (unusual) table (as you shown in question) is:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{Text 4}
    \renewcommand\rotheadgape{}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{ l llll c@{\,}X }
    \Xhline{1pt}
            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Header 1} 
                                && \cellcolor{gray!25}   \\  
    \Xcline{2-5}{0.6pt}
                &   \rothead{Text 1}
                    &   \rothead{Text 2}
                        &   \rothead{Text 3}
                            &   \rothead{Text 4}
                                &&  \cellcolor{gray!25}%
                                    \multirow{-2.2}{=}{\noindent
                                    Some line 1 Some line 2
                                    Some line 3}        \\ 
Header 3    &   &   &   &   &&  Header 3                \\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
A           &   &   &   &   &&  1                       \\
B           &   &   &   &   &&  2                       \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

**Addendum:**

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{makecell, multirow, tabularx}
\newcolumntype{L}{>{\raggedright\arraybackslash}X}
\newcommand\mrrc[1]{\multirow{-2.4}{*}{\rothead{#1}}} % <---
\usepackage[skip=1ex]{caption}

\begin{document}
    \begin{table}[htb]
    \centering
    \setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
    \settowidth\rotheadsize{Text 4}
    \renewcommand\rotheadgape{}
\begin{tabularx}{0.6\linewidth}{ l llll c@{\,}L }
    \Xhline{1pt}
            & \multicolumn{4}{c}{Header 1} 
                            && \cellcolor{gray!25}  \\  
    \Xcline{2-5}{0.6pt}
            &   &   &   &   &&  \cellcolor{gray!25}                 % <---
                                \small\linespread{0.84}\selectfont  % <---
                                \multirow{-1.8}{=}{\noindent
                                    Some line 1 
                                    Some line 2
                                    Some line 3}    \\[1ex]
Header 3    &   \mrrc{Text 1}       % <--- rotated headers moved down
                &   \mrrc{Text 2}
                    &   \mrrc{Text 3}
                        &   \mrrc{Text 4}
                                   &&  Header 3     \\
    \Xhline{0.6pt}
A           &   &   &   &   &&  1                   \\
B           &   &   &   &   &&  2                   \\
    \Xhline{1pt}
\end{tabularx}
    \end{table}
\end{document}
```

hopefully produce what you like to have:

[image]

Comment: Thanks a bunch, the requirement of my project is indeed unusual :) As an additional question, do you think it is possible to align the rotated texts to the bottom where header 3 is?

Comment: @mti, it is possible, I will show you asap.

Comment: @mti, see addendum to my answer.

Comment: Thanks a bunch! This is exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 1):

Is it what you want to have?

```
\documentclass{article}
\newcommand*\turn{\rotatebox[origin=b]{90}}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{booktabs}
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{array, caption}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage[table,xcdraw]{xcolor}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}[]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{@{}llllll@{}}
\toprule
& \multicolumn{4}{c}{Header 1} & \\
\cmidrule(lr){2-5}
&\multirowcell{3.5}{\turn{Text1}} &\multirowcell{3.5}{\turn{Text2}} &\multirowcell{3.5}{\turn{Text3}} & \multirowcell{3.5}{\turn{Text4}} & \cellcolor{gray!25} \makecell{Some line 1\\ Some line 1\\ Some line 1\\ Some line 1\\ Some line 1} \\
\addlinespace
Header 3 & & & & &Header 3\\
\midrule

& & & & & \\
& & & & & \\
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is very close. I can take it from here as I almost got I wanted. Thanks a lot for your help, really appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution with `{NiceTabular}` of `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[htb]
\centering
\setlength\extrarowheight{2pt}
\begin{NiceTabular}{llllll}
\CodeBefore
  \rectanglecolor{gray!20}{1-6}{2-6}
\Body
  \toprule
   & \Block{1-4}{Header 1} &&&
   & \Block{2-1}{Some line 1\\ Some line 2 \\ Some line 3}  \\  
  \cmidrule(lr){2-5}
   \RowStyle{\rotate}
   & Text 1
   & Text 2
   & Text 3
   & Text 4 \\
  Header 3    &   &   &   &   & Header 3 \\
  \midrule
  A           &   &   &   &   &  1 \\
  B           &   &   &   &   &  2 \\
  \bottomrule
\end{NiceTabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

- This solution uses `\booktabs` (`nicematrix` is compatible with `booktabs`). Hence, it's easy to use shorten the `\cmidrule` with `\cmidrule(rl)` (there is no need of a dummy column).
- The command `\Block` of `nicematrix` put its content at the mathematical center of the merge cells. There is no need to adjust manually as in `\multirow`.
- The command `\rowstyle` applies formatting commands to all the cells of the row.
- In `nicematrix`, the colored panels are drawn before all the rules (the output is better in the PDF viewers: the rules won't seem to disappear at some levels of zoom in some PDF viewers as Adobe Reader).

[image: Ouput of the above code]

Comment: Thanks a lot for the nice alternative :)